# Flutter Firebase Storage Futures issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm having some problems with a line in the function below. The function is handling async gets from Firebase Storage. I'm using it to get the names and urls of files I have stored there.
The issues is with getting the Urls. Specifically on the line:

```
String url = element.getDownloadURL().toString();
```

getDownloadedURL() is a Firebase future. I tried to await it, but it won't recognise the await, I guess due to "element".
The over all effect is that when I'm using this in my UI via a Future builder, the name comes out fine but the Url doesn't. It is being retrieved as the print statement shows it. But it's not being waited for, so the UI is already updated.
Been trying lots of things, but haven't found a solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Future<void> getImageData() async {
final imagesFromStorage = await fb
    .storage()
    .refFromURL('gs://little-big-deals.appspot.com')
    .child('images')
    .listAll();

imagesFromStorage.items.forEach((element) {
  print(element.name);
  String url = element.getDownloadURL().toString();
  print(url.toString());
  imageData.add(ImageData(element.name, url.toString()));
});
```

}

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use async in forEach.

Just use a for loop:

```
Future<void> getImageData() async {
  final imagesFromStorage = await fb
      .storage()
      .refFromURL('gs://little-big-deals.appspot.com')
      .child('images')
      .listAll();

  for (var element in imagesFromStorage.items) {
    print(element.name);
    String url = (await element.getDownloadURL()).toString();
    print(url.toString());
    imageData.add(ImageData(element.name, url.toString()));
  }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure, I've spent quite a lot of time on this one once so... I know the feeling ;)